# Figure Slider "Stacks"

Tags: html, css, stack, figure

I'm trying to make a *Responsive CSS Image Slider* and I'm having trouble when I put more than 5 images in a `<figure>` block. For example, when I have 8 images I want to put in the frame block, the 6th, 7th and 8th images literally go *below* the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th image (very strange issue). Here is a better representation of what I'm talking about:
[image]

I'm a fan of the game Dirty Bomb and I'm trying to make a fan-site for it. I would like *all* the HD Dirty Bomb backgrounds to be part of my slider but having so much trouble. Here is how it looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZAG3.jpg

Here is the code for the slider (which works but the 6th, 7th and 8th picture are always at the bottom!):

### HTML

```
<div class="slider">
    <figure>
        <img src="../img/bg/naderbg.png" alt>
        <img src="../img/bg/proxybg.png" alt>
        <img src="../img/bg/fletcherbg.png" alt>
        <img src="../img/bg/bushwackerbg.png" alt>
        <img src="../img/bg/sparksbg.png" alt>
        <img src="../img/bg/kirabg.png" alt>
        <img src="../img/bg/rhinobg.png" alt>
        <img src="../img/bg/artybg.png" alt>
    </figure>
</div>
```

### CSS

```css
.slider{
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slider figure{
    position:absolute;
    width:500%;
    margin:0;
    left:0;
    animation: 100s slidy infinite;
}

.slider figure img{
    width:20%;
    float:left;
}

@keyframes slidy{
    0%{left:0%;}
    10%{left:0%;}
    12%{left:-100%;}
    22%{left:-100%;}
    24%{left:-200%;}
    34%{left:-200%;}
    36%{left:-300%;}
    46%{left:-300%;}
    48%{left:-400%;}
    58%{left:-400%;}
    60%{left:-300%;}
    70%{left:-300%;}
    72%{left:-200%;}
    82%{left:-200%;}
    84%{left:-100%;}
    94%{left:-100%;}
    96%{left:0%;}
}
```

In addition, the SAME thing happens with *Dudley Storey*'s code in this website.

If you add more than 5 pictures (example you add the same pictures in his code), the 6th, 7th, 8th, etc, will go BELOW the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc

https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/ehKpi

I've been struggling with this problem for a whole day. I've been looking at tons of videos on YouTube, Internet, Stack Overflow, but I just can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set width of `.slider figure` to `100% * images count` (800% for 8 images) and set `.slider figure img` to `100% / images count` (12.5% for 8 images):

```css
@keyframes slidy {
  0% { left: 0%; }
  20% { left: 0%; }
  25% { left: -100%; }
  45% { left: -100%; }
  50% { left: -200%; }
  70% { left: -200%; }
  75% { left: -300%; }
  95% { left: -300%; }
  100% { left: -400%; }
}

body { margin: 0; } 
div#slider { overflow: hidden; }
div#slider figure img {
  width: 12.5%; 
  float: left; 
}
div#slider figure { 
  position: relative;
  width: 800%; 
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
}
```